# ERROR [IntrusionException] [SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown -> /ExampleApplication/IntrusionException] INTRUSION - Multiple (2x) encoding

Tags: xss, owasp, esapi

I have this line of code in my project :

```
try {
    ESAPI.initialize("org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration");
    value = ESAPIENCODER.canonicalize(value);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    LOG.warn("Invalid parameter value, setting to empty. Value: " + value, e);
    value = "";
}
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR [IntrusionException] [SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown ->
>   /ExampleApplication/IntrusionException] INTRUSION - Multiple (2x)
>   encoding detected in
>   http://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwscD6ifjbAhVOgK0KHT_DAYsQFggxMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nequipment.eu%2Fassets%2Fimported%2Ftransformations%2Fcontent%2Fproduct-details%2F%257Blanguage%257D_Brochure%2FC061657EB4C64903B6BEB38FBAC03445%2FDX140LC-3_AS8-3_EN.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2923Vp0vsPQHvZ7gDbPFGs
>   2018-06-29 00:29:31,559 WARN  [com.xxxxx.framework.utils.XSSUtil]
>   Invalid parameter value, setting to empty. Value:
>   http://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwscD6ifjbAhVOgK0KHT_DAYsQFggxMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nequipment.eu%2Fassets%2Fimported%2Ftransformations%2Fcontent%2Fproduct-details%2F%257Blanguage%257D_Brochure%2FC061657EB4C64903B6BEB38FBAC03445%2F140LC-3_X160LC-3_EN.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2923Vp0vsPQHvZ7gDbPFGs
>   org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntrusionException: Input validation failure
>     at
>   org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.canonicalize(DefaultEncoder.java:181)
>     at
>   org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.canonicalize(DefaultEncoder.java:122)

What does the warning mean and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: What’s the input data?

Comment: Ah, it’s a URL.  So URLs are a complicated data type, because not only are they encoded once (URI) they also typically contain HTML-escaped data because URI queries can sometimes look like HTML entities.

Comment: The next ESAPI release, 2.1.0.2 will contain a new method to canonicalize URIs that won’t display this behavior.

Comment: Thanks  avgvstvs ,so we have to wait until 2.1.0.2 release ?

Comment: Not necessarily, depending on your company's policy.  You could clone and build the current HEAD right now and get access to the method.